# Bluetooth internal card not recognized by Debian 11

Tags: debian

I have an Asus X550Z laptop.I can boot into Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, Mint 21 and Debian 11.All OS work wonderfully, except for Bluetooth on Debian 11.Ubuntu and Mint recognize the internal Bluetooth card in my Asus laptop.Debian says I have to use a Bluetooth dongle.The dongle does work, however it’s using up a USB port I could use for something else.
I have a feeling Debian 11 on installation did not load the appropriate firmware drivers for the internal Bluetooth card.
How can I fix this situation?

Comment: Welcome, Debian images with non free firmware can be found [here](https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/). If you didn't use on of them, that may be the cause of the problem. With your current installation you may need to [add non free to the repositories](https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList#Example_sources.list), then update and install `sudo apt update && sudo apt install firmware-linux-nonfree`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I ended up doing what suggested and Bluetooth now works A ok.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.